# HtmlAgilityPack Helper class

Tags: c#, parsing

Instead of writing `HtmlAgilityPack` document code over and over, I've decided to create a helper class for `HtmlAgilityPack` that prevents me that problem and adds a dispose feature for `HtmlDocuments`.

What can I do better?

```
public class HtmlParser
{
    private ArrayList Documents { get; set; }

    public HtmlParser()
    {
        Documents = new ArrayList();
    }

    ~HtmlParser()
    {
        Dispose();
    }

    public string ParseNode(string page, string xPath, ParseType type, string attributes = null)
    {
        int index = Documents.Add(new HtmlDocument());
        ((HtmlDocument)Documents[index]).LoadHtml(page);
        HtmlNode node = ((HtmlDocument)Documents[index]).DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(xPath);
        if (null != node) return type == ParseType.InnerHtml ? node.InnerHtml : type == ParseType.OuterHtml ? node.OuterHtml : type == ParseType.InnerText ? node.InnerText : node.Attributes[attributes].Value;
        return null;
    }

    public HtmlNode GetNode(string page, string xPath)
    {
        int index = Documents.Add(new HtmlDocument());
        ((HtmlDocument)Documents[index]).LoadHtml(page);
        return ((HtmlDocument) Documents[index]).DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(xPath);
    }

    public HtmlNodeCollection GetNodes(string page, string xPath)
    {
        int index = Documents.Add(new HtmlDocument());
        ((HtmlDocument)Documents[index]).LoadHtml(page);
        return ((HtmlDocument)Documents[index]).DocumentNode.SelectNodes(xPath);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (null != Documents)
            Documents.Clear();
        Documents = null;
        GC.Collect();
    }
}

public enum ParseType
{
    InnerHtml,
    OuterHtml,
    InnerText,
    Attribute
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things I've noticed.

1. This line `if (null != node) return type == ParseType.InnerHtml ? node.InnerHtml : type == ParseType.OuterHtml ? node.OuterHtml : type == ParseType.InnerText ? node.InnerText : node.Attributes[attributes].Value;` is very confusing.  You are mixing and if statement with multiple ternary really clutters up that line of code.
2. You shoud look into the [`var`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41479/use-of-var-keyword-in-c-sharp) keyword.  When the variable type is obvious, it is pretty much stand practise to use it.  I think it really cleans up code.
3. I'm not sure why you are using `GC.Collect()` in your constructor.  In C# there is not usually a need to control Garbage Collection.  The framework deals with it pretty well.
4. I would change `if (null != Documents)` to `if (Documents != null)`.  I know why that syntax is done in C/C++, but in C# it is not needed, and the latter is much more descriptive and easier to understand.
5. I would be careful about returning null from a method.  It adds extra code where the method is called to check for null.  Maybe look into the [null object design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern)

Other than that, your use of white space and indentation is very well done.  Makes reading your code much easier.

Comment: Well thank you for your very well explained answer but i have some notices. i make use of `? :` instead of creating a switch that will longer my code also i did not called GC.Collect in the constructor, am i ? otherwise all your suggestions is really helpful and i will follow them

Comment: Also i am calling Dispose in a destructor because this is a custom dispose method not an IDisposable implementation.

Comment: Generally I'm not against the ? : operator, except when it gets this big.  I'm thinking that a switch statement in a separate method would be more readable in this situation.

Comment: re: The destructor: that makes sense then :)  I didn't even notice that.  I will remove that comment.